# Not closing cursor - only pre-Android 4.0?

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor

I am testing an app on Android 4.0+ and it works great.  On 2.2/2.3, I keep having issues with `SQLlite` cursors.  The odd part if that this happens like 90% of the time when app starts.  I can't explain why it sometimes work.

Here is partial `LogCat`:

```
05-01 20:02:30.341: E/Cursor(369): Finalizing a Cursor that has not been deactivated or closed. database = /data/data/com.---.---/databases/cats.db, table = trending_watching, query = SELECT _id, item_id, item, review, review_id, cat, user, url FROM trending_watching
05-01 20:02:30.341: E/Cursor(369): android.database.sqlite.DatabaseObjectNotClosedException: Application did not close the cursor or database object that was opened here
```

Here is where problem happens:

In Splash Screen, I grab values from MySQL and put them in TWO different SQLlite Table.  I can verify the table is being populated with data.  Splash Screen exits.

The next Activity takes the two SQLLite Tables and gets the data like this:

```
    // Open Database

watchItemIdList = datasource
        .getWatchStrings(MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_TREND_WATCH_ITEM_ID);
watchUsers = datasource
        .getWatchStrings(MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_TREND_WATCH_USER);
watchCats = datasource
        .getWatchStrings(MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_TREND_WATCH_CAT);
watchReviews = datasource
        .getWatchStrings(MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_TREND_WATCH_REVIEW);
watchReviewId = datasource
        .getWatchStrings(MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_TREND_WATCH_REVIEW_ID);
watchItems = datasource
        .getWatchStrings(MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_TREND_WATCH_ITEM);
watchUrl = datasource
        .getWatchStrings(MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_TREND_WATCH_URL);

     // Close database
```

It gets the data here:

```
public List<String> getWatchStrings(String dbColumn) {

    Cursor cursor = database.query(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_WATCHING_REVIEWS,
            allTrendWatchingColumns, null, null, null, null, null);

    List<String> array = new ArrayList<String>();
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        String uname = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(dbColumn));
        array.add(uname);
    }
    return array;

}
```

The app keeps crashing, I believe from that `LogCat` on this line:

```
Cursor cursor = database.query(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_WATCHING_REVIEWS,
            allTrendWatchingColumns, null, null, null, null, null);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cursor.close();
```

just before You return, cursors have to be closed manually.

Comment: And make sure you call `cursor.close()` in a `finally` block, to guarantee it is always called.

Answer (score 0):

call this after your cursor is defined:

```
startManagingCursor(Cursor);
```

this tells the activity to begin  managing the cursor's life  based on the activity's lifecycle

Comment: I see that is deprecated?  is there a better way?  Such as not doing these type of functions on main UI thread?